# while using the prerender cli, terminal gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, prerender

I have been trying to implement this plugin using the cli in my Vue app (Vue 3)

```
vue add prerender-spa
```

. After I am done with the cli, I get this error.

```
�  Invoking generator for Vue-cli-plugin-prerender-spa...
⚓  Running completion hooks...
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at C:\Users\hp\Documents\WebDev\projects\VueAndFirebase\learnvue\Myprerender-attempt\dojo-blog\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-prerender-spa\generator.js:22:42
    at runGenerator (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\invoke.js:132:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async invoke (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\invoke.js:92:3)
```

What could be the problem, or should I just abandon this pre-rendering and focus on SSR(Nuxt.js). Although the app is a small one and based on my findings, SSR is overkill. It is giving me too much headache.